After the app launches on Android Emulator, a few seconds later windows 11 crash. Need help to fix this issue
After the app launches on Android Emulator, a few seconds later windows 11 crash. I have tried last 3 to 4 different versions of android studio and emulator but got the same issue. Its happening frequently but not all the time.
I got this issue from the idea text file in log folder
[  21565]   WARN - #c.i.u.i.d.ChangedFilesPushedDiagnostic - Failed to read C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2023.2\log\indexing-diagnostic\android.572a6fac\changed-files-pushing-events.json
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
at [Source: (String)"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000.....
need a help to fix this issue
I have tried to run android emulator on android studio. It was working fine in window10. After updating my windows from 10 to 11, when the emulator started running for a few seconds window crashes. This crashes happen frequently.
